# Java child elements stripped using .getTextContent

Tags: java, getelementsbytagname

I need to get the text with the `<br />` tags intact. I was using `getTextContent`, but it strips the inner tags.

Code:

```
var nodeList = root.getElementsByTagName("tr");
var nodeCount = nodeList.getLength();
for (row = 0; row < nodeList.getLength(); row++) {
    var node = nodeList.item(row);
    // Legacy Data Key e.g "ENV"
    var DOORSKey = new java.lang.String(node.getElementsByTagName("td").item(0).getTextContent().trim());
    var DOORSKeyCount = DOORSKey.length();
    // DOORSVal e.g. "ALL"
    var DOORSVal = new java.lang.String(node.getElementsByTagName("td").item(1).getNodeValue());
```

Sample HTML:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Customer</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ENV</td>
            <td>ALL</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Module</td>
            <td>6DOF</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Object Level</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>XML Profile</td>
            <td>DHS_CBP_HW<br />DHS_CBP_TRAIN<br />GE_B0_HW<br />GE_B0_TRAIN<br />GE_B1_HW<br />GE_B1_JSIL_TRAIN<br />GE_B1_TRAIN<br />GE-ER_HW<br />GE-ER_TRAIN<br />GTS_MQ9<br />ITALY_HW<br />ITALY_TRAIN<br />MQ1_HW<br />MQ1_PMATS_TRAIN<br />MQ1_TRAIN<br />MQ9_BLOCK5_BW_HW<br />MQ9_BLOCK5_BW_TRAIN<br />MQ9_BLOCK5_HW<br />MQ9_BLOCK5_JSIL_TRAIN<br />MQ9_BLOCK5_PMATS_TRAIN<br />MQ9_BLOCK5_TRAIN<br />MQ9_BW_HW<br />MQ9_BW_PMATS_TRAIN<br />MQ9_BW_TRAIN<br />MQ9_HW<br />MQ9_IKHANA_TRAIN<br />MQ9_JSIL_TRAIN<br />MQ9_PMATS_TRAIN<br />MQ9_SPECIAL_HW<br />MQ9_SPECIAL_TRAIN<br />MQ9_TAMLG_TRAIN<br />MQ9_TEST<br />MQ9_TRAIN<br />ORGANIC_DEPOT_HW<br />ORGANIC_DEPOT_BLOCK5_HW<br />ORGANIC_DEPOT_TRAIN<br />ORGANIC_DEPOT_BLOCK5_TRAIN<br />PREDA_ITALY_TRAIN<br />PREDB_ITALY_TRAIN<br />PREDC_AC2_HW<br />PREDC_AC2_TRAIN<br />PREDC_HW<br />PREDC_TRAIN<br />PREDEP_TRAIN<br />PREDXP_HW<br />PREDXP_TRAIN<br />RITI_HW<br />RITI_TRAIN<br />WARRIOR_A_HW<br />WARRIOR_A_JSIL_TRAIN<br />WARRIOR_A_TRAIN</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have tried to get the child tags using `.getNodeValue`. But received an error from the database.

```
var DOORSVal = new java.lang.String(node.getElementsByTagName("td").item(1).getNodeValue());
```

Comment: “But received an error from the database.”  Edit your question and show us that error.  Also, there is no reason to use `new java.lang.String`, since all String objects are immutable and can be safely shared.

Answer (score -1):

As you’ve discovered, getTextContent cannot be used for this.  You will need to use [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116) in order to preserve both text and elements.  (Only XSLT 1.0 is supposed by Java SE, currently, but this is more than sufficient for your task.)

You’ll want a template that always analyzes `<td>` elements, copies only text and `<br>` child elements, and ignores everything else:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="td" priority="2">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="br|text()" priority="1">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Java uses the [Transformer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html) class to represent an XSLT document.  The usage looks something like this:

```
String xslt = """
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                    version="1.0">

        <xsl:template match="td" priority="2">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="br|text()" priority="1">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="@*|node()"/>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
""";

Transformer transformer =
    TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(
        new StreamSource(new StringReader(xslt)));
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");

var trList = root.getElementsByTagName("tr");
var nodeCount = trList.getLength();
for (int row = 0; row < nodeCount; row++) {
    Element tr = (Element) trList.item(row);

    var tdList = tr.getElementsByTagName("td");

    StringWriter DOORSKey = new StringWriter();
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(tdList.item(0)),
                          new StreamResult(DOORSKey));

    StringWriter DOORSVal = new StringWriter();
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(tdList.item(1)),
                          new StreamResult(DOORSVal));

    System.out.println("key=" + DOORSKey + ", value=" + DOORSVal);
}
```

By the way, there is no reason to use `new java.lang.String`, since all String objects are immutable and can be safely shared.  `new String(otherString)` accomplishes nothing.